# Load template on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Is there a way, using javascript, to load a template whenever a specific select tag, changes its value? For example, a user changes the value of the select from nothing to "Template_1" then the ckeditor should load "Template_1".

HTML:

```
<select id="tipe">
  <option>Template_1</option>
</select>

<textarea class="ckeditor form-control html" id="motivo" name="motivo" rows="6" data-error-container="#editor2_error"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('motivo');
$('#tipe').change(function(){
    var template = $(this).val();
    ////Code Here to replace template
});
```

I have preloaded "Template_1" on the ckeditor templates.

Comment: Can you add some code for us to work with. If you want to go an extra step put it into JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the different templates in an object. Then, add an event listener for the input box, and set the ckeditor content.

HTML:

```
<select id="tipe">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Template_1">Template 1</option>
  <option value="Template_2">Template 2</option>
</select>

<textarea class="ckeditor form-control html" id="motivo" name="motivo" rows="6" data-error-container="#editor2_error"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var templates={};
templates["Template_1"]="<p>This is the first template</p>";
templates["Template_2"]="<p>This is the second template</p>";
$('#tipe').change(function(){
    var template = $(this).val();
    CKEDITOR.instances["motivo"].setData(templates[template])
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ybxpku8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some content template, I'm sure you're aware of [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/templates). If you want to do this anyway, I'd do what follows, if I'd like - for example - a content template with a div with a p and an image elements:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('motivo');
$('#tipe').change(function()
{
    var template = $(this).val();

    if(template == 'Paragraph with some image')
    {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.motivo;

        editor.insertElement(
         CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(
         '<div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background: #C4C4C4;">
             <p style="height: 100px; width: 50%;"></p>
             <image src="some/uri.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 50%;" />
          </div>') 
         );
     }

     //else other templates 
});
```